# Moment js not converting the date to desired format

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, momentjs

I have this arrray of objects:

```
[ 
  { id: '1', name: 'sam', entryTime: 2018-10-30T10:48:29.286Z }, 
  { id: '2', name: 'john', entryTime: 2018-10-30T11:37:23.874Z } 
]
```

My Expected output:

```
[ 
  { id: '1', name: 'sam', entryTime: 30 Oct 2018 }, 
  { id: '2', name: 'john', entryTime: 30 Oct 2018 } 
]
```

Here what i tried:

```
const visitors = [..that above array]

visitors.map(index => index.entryTime = moment(index.entryTime).format('D MMM YYYY'));
```

Getting invalid date in my object.

Answer (score 0):

convert it in date object, your date also contain time. (Date and time is separated with a capital T).

```
 var visitors  = [ 
      { id: '1', name: 'sam', entryTime: '2018-10-30T10:48:29.286Z' }, 
      { id: '2', name: 'john', entryTime: '2018-10-30T11:37:23.874Z' } 
    ];

    visitors.map(index => index.entryTime = moment(new Date(index.entryTime)).format('Do MMM YY'));
```

Comment: this is working if i check via jsfiddle, jsbin like that sttufs, but not working my node backend code.

Answer (score 0):

actually my code works, its the sequelize ORM raw data problems.

```
visitors.map(index => index.entryTime = moment(index.entryTime).format('D MMM YYYY'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for converting date as string to particular format.

```
var d = "2018-10-30T10:48:29.286Z";
var output = moment(d,'DD MMM YYYY');
```